# Как сохранять сообщения в aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Я сделал бота без БД и мне нужно чтобы сообщения пользователя, написанные ПОСЛЕ нажатия кнопки, сохранялись в переменную и отправлялись ко мне в личные сообщения, либо без сохранения в переменную сразу отправлялись в лс. Буду рад, если поможете.

кусочек кода нажатия кнопки:

```
@dp.message(F.text == 'дополнить')
    async def cmd_dop(message: Message):
    await message.answer('напиши исполнителя и название песни')
```